# How to remove blank dates from chart range in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I have the days 24, 25, 26, 27 and 30th of March for my data range:

[image: Data Range]

But no matter what I do, the missing days, 28 and 29th, are added to my x-axis in this chart, what makes my graph looks odd, when it should be a straight 45º line:

[image: Graph]

When I change my chart's type to, let's say, `Combo Chart`, it works as expected, but this is not what I want:

[image: Combo Chart]

After I change it to `Area Chart`, the missing days are added again:

[image: Area Chart]

How do I turn off this "auto-range"?

---

As requested, the formula I'm using to generate the dates.

*First date:*

`=IF(WEEKDAY(TODAY(),3) < 6,TODAY(),IF(WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1,3) < 6,TODAY()-1,IF(WEEKDAY(TODAY()-2,3) < 6,TODAY()-2)))`

*Following dates:*

`=IF(WEEKDAY(AD7-1,2) < 6,AD7-1,IF(WEEKDAY(AD7-2,2) < 6,AD7-2,IF(WEEKDAY(AD7-3,2) < 6,AD7-3)))`

*`AD7` references the cell above the current*

---

## Solution

In an adjacent range I referenced the original dates (generated by the formula) as follows:

`=MONTH(AD8)&"/"&DAY(AD8)&"/"&YEAR(AD8)`

Worked:

[image: Working Chart]

Comment: Yep. it gets translated to numbers (I'm using a formula to get the date). Even if I reference the cells in another cell I can't make them Plain Text (same thing).

Comment: Can you share the formula you are using to generate the dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent Spreadsheets from automatically formatting numbers, **put an apostrophe** (') in front of the number. For instance, the following data set does *not* insert extra dates, and shows up as "linear" as you require. Bonus: using a date format like this ensures that it sorts correctly.

Data:

```
'2015-03-25,    1
'2015-03-26,    2
'2015-03-27,    3
'2015-03-30,    4
```

Appearance in Sheets:
[image]

Chart:

[image]

Comment: Well... wasn't quite enough to add a `'` to the start of the formula. I did this `=MONTH(AD7)&"/"&DAY(AD7)&"/"&YEAR(AD7)`, where `AD7` is the original date generated by another formula and it seems to be working now. But I will accept as the right answer as it pointed me to the right path. Thanks!

Comment: @dmmd another option is to append `&""` after your formulae to force them into strings.

Comment: dmmd: Next time you can also wrap your existing formula in `=CONCAT("'", MONTH....)` (the first argument there is an apostrophe in double-quotes).

AdamL: The problem there is that any downstream references (such as in Charts) are IME likely to re-parse the strings, and put you back in the same situation as you started.

Answer (score 1):

Seems there's another way also. In customization, check `Treat labels as text` removes these extra times/dates that are in sequence but have no data. Hope this helps!